# Callback seems an object instead of a function

Tags: javascript, callback

I got really confused about callbacks. I want to use a library called node-jet and found every page on callback that callback is a function.

https://github.com/lipp/node-jet/blob/master/doc/peer.markdown

But here situation seems a little bit different and cant understand what is is. It seem callback is an object/variable instead of a function.

```
state.on('set', cb)
```

Registers a set event handler. Should be called before the state is actually added (`peer.add(state)`). The cb callback gets the new requested value passed in.

> The function is free to:
>
> - return nothing, a State change is posted automatically with the newValue
> - throw an Error, the Error should be a String or an Object with code and message
> - return on Object with the supported fields:
>   value: {Any, Optional} the "real/adjusted" new value. This is posted as the new value.
>   dontNotify: {Boolean, Optional} Don't auto-send a change Notification

```
john.on('set', function(newValue) {
  var prev = this.value();
  if (newValue.age < prev.age){
    throw 'invalid age';
  }
  return {
    value: {
      age: newValue.age,
      name: newValue.name || prev.name
    }
  };
});
```

In an example using same library

```
// create a new todo state and store ref.

 var todoState = new jet.State('todo/#' + todo.id, todo)
 todoState.on('set', function (requestedTodo) {
  todo.merge(requestedTodo)
  return {
    value: todo
  }
})
todoStates[todo.id] = todoState
peer.add(todoState)
```

Comment: In javascript, a function can be stored in a variable.
and in fact, a function **is** a special type of object. you can add attribute to function like you would with object.

Comment: Whats the question? You can think of functions at callable objects if that's what you are confused about. Think [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) where you can chain by calling, eg `_(obj).values().value()` or use as an obj `_.values(obj)`